# What is a Storage Deposit?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, storage, contracts, gas

When developing `ink` smart contracts, I've often seen a `Storage Deposit` charge. What is this, and how does it relate to contract storage?

My guess is it's a charge related to the size of the contract's storage, so the larger the data store for a contract the higher the gas fee per tx for that contract. Is that correct? If so, how is the fee decided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage deposit is the payment for the contract storage.

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0cdf7029017b70b7c83c21a4dc0aa1020e7914f6/frame/contracts/primitives/src/lib.rs#L57-L63

It is used to pay for onchain storage for a contract, reduce storage bloat, and protect against spamming or a DOS attack.

There is also a storage deposit limit which is the maximum storage deposit that can be charged from the caller for the storage consumed.

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0cdf7029017b70b7c83c21a4dc0aa1020e7914f6/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L692

Edit by @goastler on 19/08/2023:
I've gone through the code linked above trying to work out how the storage deposit is charged. [Here's](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/94be94be6d26becd2395b58ae09ca31f596afe7d/frame/contracts/src/storage.rs#L50) the struct representing the contract. Whenever a contract's storage is changed, the difference in the size from before and after is charged to the caller (I believe this can be a refund if the contract storage has shrunk in total) - see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/94be94be6d26becd2395b58ae09ca31f596afe7d/frame/contracts/src/storage.rs#L192C20-L192C20) and [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/94be94be6d26becd2395b58ae09ca31f596afe7d/frame/contracts/src/storage/meter.rs#L215C14-L215C14). This is taken out of the gas for the transaction